# Show code details in exception messages settings

Tags: java, exception, java-14

I've just used -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages in my java application and checked the changes in output details, I want to see whether this is configurable by users or developers to show some kinds of exceptions with more details or it is affecting all the exceptions?

And if it is configurable, am I able to set customize models depending on the teams and people who are working or testing a project?

Comment: Why don't you try some `logging API`  after collecction of events then customize after that.